# Single billing cylce for paypal subscription?

Tags: paypal

The subscriptions method only allows at least 2 billing cycles. What's the best alternative method I should use?

Comment: Are you referring to the Trial #1, Trial #2, and Regular Subscription payments/intervals referenced in the documentation or ..? Referring to: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf

Comment: No, I am talking about billing cycle. I'd like to create a single payment method, meaning a subscriber only pays once. As far as I know, it's not possible using the subscription method because the minimum billing cycle is two and that would require a subscriber to pay twice which I don't want.. I am looking into using "buy now" method instead but I'd like to solicit ideas first. Sorry, I thought it was easy enough to understand.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal has the Buy Now button for single payments and the subscription services for mulitple payments. If you only want someone to pay once, then you should be using a buy now button.